# Fail-over VPN with two ISPs and Cisco ASA 5500 Series

Tags: vpn, cisco, cisco-asa, failover, isp

We have a couple of branch offices that need to connect to a main site.
We plan to use Cisco ASAs 5515 to establish VPN connections. We would also like to have 2 ISPs at each location to make the connection redundant. Here is the image:
[image]

I am a bit new to ASAs so far, so my question is "Is it possible to set up ASA 5515 to use 2 ISPs to have VPN connection with a remote site and in case of the main ISP's failure switch over to backup ISP automatically and then to return back to the main one when the link is reestablished ?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, all you have to do is enable isakmp on the both outside interfaces of the redundant ISP ASA with

```
crypto isakmp enable <outside interface name>
crypto isakmp enable <backup interface name>
```

and then on the ISP C ASA change your crypto map statement to:

```
crypto map outside_map <crypto map no> set peer <ISP A IP> <ISP B IP>
```

That will allow a failover if ISP A is down. When the tunnel is renegotiated and ISP A is available the tunnel will fail back.